# NodeJS Passport - how to open a new window for authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm using Passport for NodeJS for authentication. I've successfully integrated it. If the user has his Github credentials already in his cookies, he just clicks my login button and he's on my dashboard.  However, if he doesn't have cookies, my app will redirect him to Github temporarily to enter his credentials.

I want to add the functionality that if the app has to redirect the user to Github, do so in a new window. Is this possible?

In the passport-github example this function is called, but apparently I can't run any code when this happens?

```
// GET /auth/github
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route m function(req,res)iddleware to authenticate the
//   request.  The first step in GitHub authentication will involve redirecting
//   the user to github.com.  After authorization, GitHubwill redirect the user
//   back to this application at /auth/github/callback
app.get('/auth/github',
  passport.authenticate('github'),
  function(req, res){
    // The request will be redirected to GitHub for authentication, so this
    // function will not be called.
  });
```

Comment: this is not a node.js server side solution, but a js/html solution.. please update your question with the relative piece of codes from your js/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to have the user redirect in a different window? Doesn't the GitHub auth send the user back to your application via a redirect?

Maybe try:

```
window.open('/auth/github')
```

Comment: because this is happening in a popup chrome extension box that won't go to github because github doesn't show allow showing up in a small window. so it just doesn't reach github unless i use a big window. try that code snippet where?